# Guessing a string with time comparison. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, c, time, cryptography, brute-force

I was wondering about a strange idea: you are given and algorithm wich takes a string in input and compares it to a string that you don't know. The algoritm is just a trivial comparison, one char at a time. When a couple that doesn't match is found, 0 is returned. Otherwise it returns 1.

Can you guess the secret string in a polynomial time by using the provided algorithm?

When a string doesn't match, the time used to give the answer 0 is less than the time taken to return 1, because less comparisons are needed. Times involved are very small, and for this reason you can try a single instance many times to get a more accurate estimation. Estimating the time taken we could have informations about the secret string. If this works properly, we can guess the string one char at a time, in a polynomial time. So if this can happen we can try some kind of brute force attack char by char.

Does this make sense? Or is there something I'm misunderstanding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, I was just wondering. There have been a lot of homework questions recently.

Comment: Simply trying to guess 10-letter string will take 26^10 tries. If you want to guess using provided method, you'll need to do like a hundred of tries on each letter, which increases the amount of tries needed to (26*100)^10, which is pretty unrealistic.

Comment: @Ranty Absolutely not. Assuming accurate timings, it takes 26 tries to guess the first letter, and then 26 tries to guess the second one, ..., and the 10-letter string can be guessed in 260 tries. That's if you are most unlucky but have perfect measurements. If you are less unlucky but have imperfect measurement, you may need 10 times that.

Comment: That's the point. Doing like this the problem becomes linear.

Comment: @Vector also, doing it like this won't work. Since a 1 letter string won't match the 10 letter secret and you can't [apparently] can't control the size of the secret string. Admittedly, this may be reading the specification differently than it is meant.

Comment: Vector if you're interesting in that topic, search for so called "timing side channel attacks". Some of these are really fancy, like exploiting caching effect to get a timing on a function, which algorithm in theory should execute O(1). Other side channels are the power consumed by the CPU (and you can measure that quite accurately with the hardware monitors these days) and the effect the execution of a crypto function has on the caches of *other* programs, i.e. even if the crypto doesn't exhibit a timing effect, other parts of the system may be. This is crazy stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can guess the secret string if you can can input your own strings to compare, or just observe enough strings (not chosen by you) being compared to the secret string, **if the string comparison has been written in a way such that its execution time reveals information about the secret string**.

This is a known weakness cryptographic software can have, and all serious cryptographic software written nowadays avoids this weakness.

For instance, to avoid revealing information about its arguments, a function that tests whether two buffers are the same or different may be written:

```
int crypto_memcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)
{
  size_t i;
  int answer;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    answer = answer | (s1[i] != s2[i]);
  return answer;
}
```

You can use several techniques to check that a piece of code does not leak secrets through timing attacks. I wrote how to do it with static analysis [here](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/12/31/Do-not-use-AES-in-a-context-where-timing-attacks-are-possible) but this is based on a previous idea that used Valgrind (dynamic analysis) [here](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/04/01/ctgrind.html).

Note that it goes further than that. [This article](http://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf) showed how you did not even need the execution path to depend on the secret to leak information. It was enough that the secret was used in the computation of some array indices that were subsequently accessed. On modern computers, this changes the execution time because the cache will make two successive accesses to similar indices faster than two successive accesses to indices that are far from each other, revealing information about the secret.

Comment: `answer` is not initialized, so there's no telling what the result might be for `answer = answer | ...`. It could always return non-zero. Its a great way to confuse an attacker if correctness is not required.

Comment: `s1[i] != s2[i]` might produce a conditional branch. You might consider using `s1[i] ^ s2[i]` instead.

Comment: @noloader Fair enough. Actually I have a blog post coming up about “attacks by compiler” where the attacker submits a patch to an open-source compiler, the patch being accepted because it generally speeds things up but also introducing back side-channel leaks when compiling source code that tries to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the string bit by bit. for each bit use **binary search**

for example:

you already know the first a bits. say it (Sa).

now you have to determine the (a+1)th bit.

there are upper bound `(Sa)zzzzzzz...` and lower bound `(Sa)azzzzzz...`.

first you guess the (a+1)th bit is `(a+z)/2`, say `r`, then the string is `(Sa)rzzzzzz...`, and with the result, you update the upper bound and lower bound.

Comment: The string comparison usually doesn't work bit-by-bit (it compares whole bytes or even greater chunks of data at once), and you (as an attacker) don't get greater-smaller-results, only "matches for n chunks" (if at all). So it isn't that easy as you say.